# JNLP Webstart + JavaFX and DeployToolkit

Tags: java, deployment, javafx-2, jnlp, java-web-start

I've been searching and trying Webstart some days now. Some of the application users have issues related to java - but that's okay, sth. that is easy fixable.

However there are many questions I have:

1. The Icon image is always downloaded again from the server. I tried using the attribute version="", however then my icon cannot be found. I renamed the image file to the same format my jar resources have filename_*V$version$.jar -> filename*_V$version%.png. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?
2. I'm using JavaFX and with JavaFX Webstart got some new elements, for example jfx:javafx-runtime... I couldn't find any description / documentation which "new" elements are existing and I didnt find any namespace for jfx either. This results in having no way to check my jnlp file for validity. Additionally the default Webstart launcher is no longer displayed. I currently could fix this by creating a custom progress indicator but isn't there any native solution?
3. Java Webstart shows once beginning the installation a Java7 Splashscreen. Is there any way to hide this? To see this behavior you could start the installation http://youtubeuploader.square7.ch/nightly/ - you dont have to finish it though.
4. Is there any complete documentation / api for the new deploymentToolkit introduced with JavaFX (dtjava.js)

Regards,
Dennis Fischer

Edit: Included current JNLP file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" codebase="http://youtubeuploader.square7.ch/nightly/data" href="http://youtubeuploader.square7.ch/nightly/data/SimpleJavaYoutubeUploader3.0.jnlp">
<information>
                        <title>Simple Java Youtube Uploader 3.0</title>
                        <vendor>Dennis Fischer aka CHAOSFISCH</vendor>
                        <description>Simple Java Youtube Uploader that helps you uploading videos to your favourite video platform (youtube).</description>
                        <homepage href="http://code.google.com/p/simple-java-youtube-uploader/"/>
                        <icon href="http://youtubeuploader.square7.ch/nightly/images/icon.png"/>
                        <icon kind="splash" href="http://youtubeuploader.square7.ch/nightly/images/splash.png"/>
                        <icon kind="shortcut" href="http://youtubeuploader.square7.ch/nightly/images/icon.png"/>
                        <offline-allowed/>
                        <shortcut online="true" install="true">
                            <desktop/>
                            <menu submenu="SimpleJavaYoutubeUploader">
                                <menu submenu="SimpleJavaYoutubeUploader"/>
                            </menu>
                        </shortcut>
                    </information><security>
                        <all-permissions/>
                    </security><resources>
                        <property name="jnlp.packEnabled" value="true"/>
                        <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true"/>
                        <j2se version="1.7.0.09+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
                        <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/><jar href="SimpleJavaYoutubeUpl.jar" size="467908" version="a3eed954cab539117aa17a786c01454d" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/xmlpull-1.1.3.1..jar" size="4989" version="e27ea23afcb18f5aecf099c84ca43d02" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/mail-1.4.5.jar.p.jar" size="196338" version="4070ac4943d6adb3af259067dde24733" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/WebstartProgress.jar" size="3236" version="238c19b333f9f9a46d13326b45c71abf" download="progress"/>
<jar href="lib/aopalliance-1.0..jar" size="2735" version="9e61869680381a8f71aa1fde530bbb12" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-logging-.jar" size="30947" version="9036fbe6150b7f30e090b80bc1a2a209" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-email-1..jar" size="20195" version="edce8c0ac33553ebf5ebbb7182661faf" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/httpmime-4.2.1.j.jar" size="14761" version="9918a4c7dcc1d5fc6aa0a8c13357a75b" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/logback-classic-.jar" size="83594" version="bdcd2936c1b843a228e00018ba829697" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/jfx-dialogs.jar..jar" size="16337" version="53019dac238b574ae94c5db901682ae6" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/xpp3_min-1.1.4c..jar" size="16309" version="a65c0872e018d7d69d1e47f58ac14105" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/javax.inject-1.j.jar" size="2036" version="91e135b600db7218af1bb13c37476718" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/h2-1.3.168.jar.p.jar" size="502628" version="8f4e15d4696eb6dc5c1eabbbf61700d2" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/httpcore-4.2.1.j.jar" size="76244" version="7d4d0a2eca715ec75ce0748f6bfcc533" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/xstream-1.4.3.ja.jar" size="139459" version="4e9dbf9610247f133cb3035918d2592f" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/guava-13.0.1.jar.jar" size="506336" version="90c7baa9d433534691e66f2e84292454" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/guice-3.0.jar.pa.jar" size="210949" version="177c08ff4043c627fe6a32ba05452c72" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/activation-1.1.j.jar" size="29979" version="b938264457ab34aa08aa771629d20f33" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/logback-core-1.0.jar" size="120777" version="f19bfdba6cddf705a5ad624fb0f52679" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/javassist-3.16.1.jar" size="221225" version="75590a448d2fbc359ff59a1c4e6dbc89" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/httpclient-4.2.1.jar" size="134898" version="1743a9b2d33ea9c99c21933f9bcde36a" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/gridfx-0.1-SNAPS.jar" size="13254" version="c924721aec5104345d08c820a2eee8b7" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/activejdbc-instr.jar" size="8719" version="ba39d8d62282981812afcc850f348c13" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar.jar" size="178703" version="aba0364b41c132eddca8963c64d704f9" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-codec-1..jar" size="90018" version="2eaf832b73c8464f94b959b59ba80555" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/jfxtras-labs-2.2.jar" size="460059" version="a5e9cf91a26d70b10f1c2fd4c5f386e8" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/javalite-common-.jar" size="19157" version="eb399e8ca823d94dbd3133e9e2326565" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/slf4j-api-1.7.1..jar" size="12861" version="e97494fc57464f529b84679b46da722a" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/eventbus-1.4.jar.jar" size="31417" version="a7060d516ce50f38760353ec8a7f78f5" download="lazy"/>
<jar href="lib/activejdbc-1.4.5.jar" size="52819" version="bfa0ca863f9ee96aa82a58a4a3bbd3f7" download="lazy"/>
</resources>
                    <application-desc main-class="org.chaosfisch.youtubeuploader.SimpleJavaYoutubeUploader" progress-class="org.chaosfisch.webstart.ProgressIndicator"/>
   <update check="always" policy="always"/>
    </jnlp>
```

Comment: Regarding q3: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#206

Comment: I should include my jnlp in the question above :P. I've already set this option. Still the Java 7 splash screen is shown once the application installation is started.
Edit: This could be due to the Java Deployment toolkit. I just have to check this now

Comment: Mh, So I've done some additional researches. q3 might not be resolvable because it's the browser that start Java Webstart and therefor this splashlogo is displayed. However, now I got a new problem: How to notify my application that it has been updated?